# Unable to start Service with intent caused by "NetworkOnMainThreadException"

Tags: android, sockets, exception, android-intent, service

I am working with images to send on the device, that works fine when I am using Async Task it works well  but the problem is when I do it via Service it doesn't work and I get this error, "Unable to start Service with intent caused by "NetworkOnMainThreadException"". I am actually passing the byte[] from MainActivity to Service
I need to use service because OnReceive method of BroadcastReceiver cannot respond to Async task.

Thank you!

In the Mainfest.xml

```
 <service android:name=".SendImageClientService"/>
```

MainActivity

```
    private BroadcastReceiver wifiStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int wifiStateExtra = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,
                    WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN); 

            if(wifiStateExtra==WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED){
               sendingDrawableImage();
            }else if(wifiStateExtra==WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please Check Your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    };

      private void sendingDrawableImage() {

        drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
        bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] array = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

        Intent serviceIntent=new Intent(this,SendImageClientService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("byte",array);
        this.startService(serviceIntent);
        }

  @Override
    protected void onStart() { 
        super.onStart();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new 
        IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION); 
        registerReceiver(wifiStateReceiver, intentFilter);
    }
```

Service class

```
public class SendImageClientService extends Service {

    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {

            byte[] bytesss=intent.getByteArrayExtra("byte");

            Socket socket = new Socket("ip_address_here", 8888);

            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(out);
            dataOutputStream.write(bytesss);
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(SendImageClientService.this, "Image sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            dataOutputStream.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return START_STICKY;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you meant to extend `IntentService` instead of plain `Service`. You would then move everything you have in `onStartCommand()` to `onHandleIntent()`, and delete that `onStartCommand()` override.

Comment: I tried this, now I don't have any error but still in the onReceive method this doesn't work which means when the app is in running state and I turn on the internet, the image is not being sent but when I pause and resume then only the image is sent @MikeM.

Comment: Well, that's a different issue. Also, I have no idea what `BroadcastReceiver` or `onReceive()` method you're talking about.

Comment: I've updated the code to show BroadcastReceiver @MikeM.

Answer (score 0):

the documentation says:

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process; the
>   service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate
>   process unless you specify otherwise. If your service is going to
>   perform any CPU-intensive work or blocking operations, such as MP3
>   playback or networking, you should create a new thread within the
>   service to complete that work. By using a separate thread, you can
>   reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors, and the
>   application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction
>   with your activities.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

so, you need to create new thread in your service for a long operation.

Also, you need to know, that Services are using for a long background tasks and IntentServices are using for a short background tasks. But IntentService work in separate thread.

You can use something like this:

```
new Handler().post(runnable)
```

where runnable is your long operation action (like internet action or database action). Handler is a specific class for working with thread in android.

Edit.

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {
handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
            byte[] bytesss=intent.getByteArrayExtra("byte");

            Socket socket = new Socket("ip_address_here", 8888);

            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(out);
            dataOutputStream.write(bytesss);   

            dataOutputStream.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        });

        return START_STICKY;

    }
```

Comment: I used this method as per you said, but now the problem is the image is not being sent when I turn on the wifi onReceive method works only when I pause and then resume the activity

Comment: show us your broadcast receiver and other code for its work

Comment: Also, it seems, that the problem is in broadcast receiver. What OS version do you use? Here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts you can check your broadcast receiver proper registration form.

Comment: I've updated the code for showing Broadcast Receiver

Comment: what that mean by? and why should I need to do?

Comment: You can see, when your receiver works. Maybe your `int wifiStateExtra = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,
                    WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN); ` just retrun to you `WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN`

Comment: if(wifiStateExtra==WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) this condition is getting true I have checked it. Even the sendingDrawableImage() method is also running but the service don't run as expected the image is still not sending